# Multiple SSH config files

Tags: ssh

I like the ability to specify hosts/identity files/etc in the ssh_config file. However, I would ideally like to have a couple different SSH configurations each under their own version control. Is there any way to reference another ssh_config type file from within ssh_config?

Something like this (the `Load` syntax is what I am looking for but can't find in the [man pages](http://www.manpager.com/linux/man5/ssh_config.5.html).

**~/.ssh/config**

```
Load config_file_a
Load config_file_b
```

**~/.ssh/config_file_a**

```
# Options for one host
Host serverA
    HostName serverA.myserver.com
```

**~/.ssh/config_file_b**

```
# Options for another host
Host serverB
    HostName serverB.myserver.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do that that I know of. If you really need to do this I'd suggest scripting it - i.e. write a script like so (assuming bash script, but you could use whatever your OS supports):

```
cat /path/to/config1 /path/to/config2 .... /path/to/configN > ~/.ssh/config
```

Rerun your script whenever you make a change to any one of your config files. Better yet, if your version control system supports script-hooks, automate it.

Comment: I'm leaning towards an approach like this. Only downside is that I was hoping to allow it to work with existing `ssh_config`s. I think I'm going to just append it to whatever is there and include some kind of placeholder so I can replace it if something changes

Answer (score 10):

Since [OpenSSH v7.3](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3) in 2016, you can use `Include` as per `man ssh_config`:

```
Include
             Include the specified configuration file(s).  Multiple
             pathnames may be specified and each pathname may contain
             glob(7) wildcards and, for user configurations, shell-like
             ‘~’ references to user home directories.  Wildcards will be
             expanded and processed in lexical order.  Files without
             absolute paths are assumed to be in ~/.ssh if included in a
             user configuration file or /etc/ssh if included from the
             system configuration file.  Include directive may appear
             inside a Match or Host block to perform conditional
             inclusion.
```